# Find all files of a given extension when a specific file type exists in another directory

Tags: vb.net, powershell

## Description

Using Powershell, I am trying to find a list of .vb files that exist in any folder, but only if the bin folder in that directory contains any .compiled file.  I will be running this on 1 directory which will contain many folders.  The trouble I am having is that the bin folder will not always be at the same depth in the folder structure.  I have outlined this with sudo code and examples below.  Be sure to see the final result at the very end of the post.  Thanks!

### Sudo Code

**if** any `'*.compiled'` file exists in `d:/inetpub/[Unspecified_Number_of_directories]/x/bin`

**then** Find all files recursively in `d:/inetpub/[Unspecified_Number_of_directories]/x` with extension `'*.vb'`

### Examples

execute directory: `d:/inetpub`

**example 1:**

```
d:/inetpub/123/abc
/bin/
-code.dll
-morecode.dll
-lesscode.compiled
/folder1/
-compiledPage.aspx
-regularPage.aspx
-regularPage.aspx.vb
-anotherPage.aspx
-anotherPage.aspx.vb
/folder2/
-auth.vb
```

*Should result:*

```
d:/inetpub/123/abc/folder1/regularPage.aspx.vb
d:/inetpub/123/abc/folder1/anotherPage.aspx.vb
d:/inetpub/123/abc/folder2/auth.vb
```

**example 2:**

```
d:/inetpub/123/xyz
/bin/
-code.dll
-morecode.dll
-lesscode.dll
/folder1/
-compiledPage.aspx
-regularPage.aspx
-regularPage.aspx.vb
-anotherPage.aspx
-anotherPage.aspx.vb
/folder2/
-auth.vb
```

*Should result:*

```
Nothing
```

**example 3:**

```
d:/inetpub/456
/bin/
-less.compiled
/folder1/
-test.aspx
-test.aspx.vb
/folder2/
-auth.vb
```

*should result:*

```
d:/inetpub/456/folder1/test.aspx.vb
d:/inetpub/456/folder2/auth.vb
```

### Finally

It is important to note that it should be going through all of these examples in one run.  I will not be running this script for every folder, but rather the root folder `'d:/inetpub'`.  So there would be only one list of results that would look like this:

```
d:/inetpub/123/abc/folder1/regularPage.aspx.vb
d:/inetpub/123/abc/folder1/anotherPage.aspx.vb
d:/inetpub/123/abc/folder2/auth.vb
d:/inetpub/456/folder1/test.aspx.vb
d:/inetpub/456/folder2/auth.vb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd go a slightly different route than Trevor. Query for the *.compiled files, and when it finds one search that object's directory recursively for *.vb files for each *.compiled file.

```
GCI D:\inetpub -include *.compiled -recurse|%{GCI "$($_.directory)\.." -include *.vb -recurse|Select FullName}
```

If that gets you duplicate files (this would happen if you have multiple .compiled files in one folder) you can toss `|Select -Unique` on the end of that to resolve that issue. It would slow it down though, so I wouldn't do that unless needed.

I tried to edit the script to only include .compiled files located in folders named 'bin' but it failed. Sorry. I did add `|Select FullName` in there to give a listing more like what you had asked for instead of filesystem objects. Now it just lists full path and filename like you wanted.

Comment: I do indeed have several .compiled files in the directory.  So I'm trying this with Select -Unique now.  However, some of my directories have thousands of files in them, can you suggest anything for ignoring those directories?  Or, only searching for .compiled files in 'bin' directories?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work for you:

```
$Compiled = Get-ChildItem -Path d:\inetpub\*\x\bin -Include *.compiled -Recurse;
if ($Compiled) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path d:\inetpub\*\x -Include *.vb -Recurse;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this also picks up the files in example 2.